# AWS S3 node.js SDK uploaded file and folder permissions

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm uploading file to S3 using aws-sdk package:

```
fs.readFile(sourceFile, function (err, data) {
    if (err) { throw err; }

    s3.client.putObject({
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Key: 'Folder/image.jpg',
        Body: data
    }, function (res) {
            console.log('Successfully uploaded file.');
        })

});
```

I I need to make uploaded file to be downloadable via cloudfront, if I asume right, I need to set permissions on file: Everyone Open/Download, Folder2 should be made public (via menu Make Public). So 2 questions:

1) How to set\modify permissions on uploaded file\folder?

2) How make Folder public using AWS SDK for node.js.

Answer (score 152, accepted):

Found it
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ACLOverview.html#CannedACL

need to add option in `putObject` or `upload`:

```
ACL:'public-read'
```

Comment: Is that an option you put in with the first object you passed into `putObject`?  Meaning, was it a property alongside `Bucket`, `Key`, and `Body`?

Comment: I had the above question too, so just to answer it for those that may have it as well, ```ACL:'public-read'``` should be added in with the ```Bucket```, ```Key``` and ```Body``` object that is sent to S3. Thanks to @WHITECOLOR for the help!

Comment: I assume you found an answer at some point, but in case you didn't, yes, you pass the ACL property along with 'Bucket' and 'Key'.

Comment: Note that the IAM permission "s3:PutObjectACL" must be included in the appropriate policy.

Comment: any idea why there would be access denied when the user has the permission AmazonS3FullAccess ?

Answer (score 44):

The following works like a charm. (**Note the ACL key in params**)

```js
const params = {
  Bucket: bucketName + path,
  Key: key,
  Body: buffer,
  ContentEncoding: 'base64',
  ContentType: 'image/jpeg',
  ACL:'public-read'
};
await s3.putObject(params).promise();
```

**Note**: IAM permission "**s3:PutObjectACL**" must be included in the appropriate policy otherwise you will get **Access Denied** errors.

Answer (score 26):

Here is a working code snippet that uploads a local file (test-file.gif) to S3 bucket and prints out a URL for everyone to download.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({ region: 'us-west-1' });

// Fill in your bucket name and local file name:
const BUCKET_NAME = 'test-bucket-name-goes-here'
const FILE_NAME_LOCAL = './test-file.gif'
const FILE_NAME_S3 = 'this-will-be-the-file-name-on-s3.gif'
const FILE_PERMISSION = 'public-read'

// Create S3 service object
s3 = new AWS.S3({ apiVersion: '2006-03-01' });

// Get file stream
const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(FILE_NAME_LOCAL);

// Upload the file to a specified bucket
const uploadParams = {
    Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
    Key: FILE_NAME_S3,
    Body: fileStream,
    ACL: FILE_PERMISSION
};

s3.upload(uploadParams, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error", err);
    } if (data) {
        console.log("Upload Success", data.Location);
    }
});
```