# Save objects in AWS S3 bucket with public access permission

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-js, aws-sdk-nodejs

In S3 bucket every time I create a folder with the dynamic name and multiple images with private access permission that is fine, One image I need to grant permission as public access, I am using aws-sdk Javascript here my code for saving Image I need to give public access permission

```
const Aws = require('aws-sdk');
const Bucket_Name=process.env.BUCKET_NAME;
const IAm_user_Key=process.env.IAM_USER_KEY;
const IAm_user_Secret=process.env.IAM_USER_SECRET;
const uniqueID = getuniqueid();

///Setting AWS
Aws.config.update({ accessKeyId:IAm_user_Key,secretAccessKey:IAm_user_Secret,region:'ap-south-1' });

//Setting S3 Bucket
var s3Bucket = new Aws.S3({params: {Bucket: Bucket_Name}});

//Setting up poster 
var poster = new Buffer(data.poster.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, ""),'base64');
var posterdata = { Key: (uniqueID+'/poster'), Body: poster, ContentEncoding: 'base64', ContentType: 'image/png'};
    saveImagetos3(posterdata);

function saveImagetos3(data){
        s3Bucket.putObject(data, function(err, data){
            if (err) { 
              console.log(err,"Error uploading image");
            } else {
              console.log('succesfully uploaded the image!');
            }
        });
    }

function getuniqueid(){
  //Some blah blah code for create random id
  return randomID;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AWS S3 node.js SDK uploaded file and folder permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14375895/aws-s3-node-js-sdk-uploaded-file-and-folder-permissions)

Comment: Thanks but I am facing error 'Access denied' while saving public read file, maybe bucket permission issue...

Comment: sorry I didn't find that solution but that dosen't work for me too, I feel maybe my IAM policy issue, here is my IAM policy {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::only4laughbucket"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

Comment: Is this policy attached to the IAM user you are using?

Comment: @Deiv yes this is my IAM user custom policy.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36272286/getting-access-denied-when-calling-the-putobject-operation-with-bucket-level-per

Answer (score 0):

I got know My Mistake, I set these all options to True, but I got know when we set ACL:'public-access' and in our put request then request rejects with error: Access DENIED as per Docs [Amazon S3 Blocking Public access](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/access-control-block-public-access.html), I just reset the setting to false and it works for me.